# How to temporarily disable a key in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to temporarily disable the effect of a mouse button during part of a command, but still be able to detect whether it's been pressed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
R::
if (CommandIsRunningYeah = 0)
{
Send R
}
Return
```

And then set `CommandIsRunningYeah` to 1 at the start of your command, and 0 at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply put a `Return` statement as the first command?  For example, the following command minimizes any window when you click twice on it with the right mouse key, within 500ms.

```
~RButton::
  Return ; THIS HOTKEY IS DISABLED
  If (A_PriorHotkey != A_ThisHotkey OR A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 500)
    Return
  Sleep 250
  Send {Esc}
  WinMinimize, A
  Return
```

NOTE: `Sleep 250` waits for the context menu and then `Send {Esc}` closes it.  If it wasn't disabled.